# How can I show content of closure function in the console? #javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

CLOSURES IN JAVASCRIPT
Hi there,
I am facing some struggles with my javascript code, maybe you can help with the issue about closures.
this is my code:

```
function seatReservation(aSeat) { 
    let secret = aSeat;
    return function (){
        return secret;
    }
};

class Reservations { 
    #aMailadress;
    #mySeatList;

    constructor(aMailadress){
        this.#aMailadress = aMailadress;
        this.#mySeatList = [];
    } 

    addSeatReservation(aSeat){
        this.#mySeatList.push(aSeat);
    }

    printReservations(){
        this.#mySeatList.forEach(seat => {
            console.log(seat);
        });
    }
};

// Test
const list = new Reservations('peter@mail.com');
list.addSeatReservation(new seatReservation('D3'));
list.addSeatReservation(new seatReservation('F6'));
list.printReservations();
```

the output in the console is:
[(Anonymous function)]
[(Anonymous function)]

Expected output:
D3
F6

Who can help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new seatReservation('D3')` creates a function which will, when called, return the `secret` passed to it. You could for example do: `console.log(seat());`. You call the function, thus retrieving the data from the closure.